# How to get all the nodes and edges connected to a certain node in networkx?

Tags: python, python-3.x, networkx

I have created a simple undirected graph in Python networkx library:

```
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

G = nx.Graph()
G.add_nodes_from(["A", "B", "C", "D", "E"])
G.add_edges_from([("A","C"), ("B","D"), ("B","E"), ("C", "E"), ("A", "E"), ("E", "D")])
#pos = nx.random_layout(G)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
nx.draw_networkx(G, pos=pos, ax=ax)
fig.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

I would like to return a subgraph of all the nodes and edges connected to a certain node. As an example, if the node is "A", the connected nodes are "C" and "E". So it should return these 3 nodes and the edges between them.

This is what I tried following a couple other StackOverflow answers:

```
node = "A"
# connected_nodes = nx.shortest_path(G,node).keys()
connected_nodes = list(nx.node_connected_component(G, "A"))
connected_edges = G.edges([node])
print(connected_nodes)
print(connected_edges)

H = nx.Graph()
H.add_nodes_from(connected_nodes)
H.add_edges_from(connected_edges)

# https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33088008/fetch-connected-nodes-in-a-networkx-graph
# https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63169294/how-to-plot-a-subset-of-nodes-of-a-networkx-graph
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
nx.draw_networkx(H, pos=pos, ax=ax)
fig.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

The current output looks like this (almost there!) but I am getting more nodes returned than I should:

[image]

How do I fix it?

Comment: and if you omit `H.add_nodes_from(connected_nodes)` does it give the expected output?

Comment: it does!! My intuition was really not expecting it.

Comment: but `A -> E` and `E -> D`

Answer (score 1):

@RomanPerekhrest pointed it out as comment, it was a simply as taking out

```
H.add_nodes_from(connected_nodes)
```

So the solution is:

```
node = "A"
connected_edges = G.edges([node])
print(connected_edges)

H = nx.Graph()
H.add_edges_from(connected_edges)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
nx.draw_networkx(H, pos=pos, ax=ax)
fig.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```